# Generate fake hierarchical data in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I need to generate fake data for MS SQL database. Let's say I have following tables:

- ClientGroup
- Subgroup
- Category
- Range
- Country
- Client

Each table has columns id, parent_id. Also each record can be considered as top level ( parent_id = null ), or as lower level in hierarchy ( parent_id is set to some value).

Besides those columns each child table points to parentid via parent_Entity_Id .

Following hierarchies can be applicable:

ClientGroup 1 -> ClientGroup 2 -> ClientGroup 3 -> Subgroup -> Category -> Range -> Country -> Client

ClientGroup 1 and ClientGroup 2 and ClientGroup 3 in the table ClientGroup.

ClientGroup -> Subgroup 1-> Subgroup 2-> Category -> Range -> Country -> Client.
Subgroup 1 and Subgroup 2 also in the same table Subgroup.

And the following schema can also happen:

ClientGroup -> Subgroup -> Category -> Range -> Country -> Client

Are there any tools, which I may use in order to generate such fake hierarchical data?

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around your structure.  Particularly why you have a parent_id field and a second parent_Entity_Id. What is the primary key of your tables?  Do you have a master table for each of the types?  Maybe if you add some sample data it would help.

Comment: Entity in table can be parent to to another entity(s) in the same table. Parent_entity_id points to parent in another table. Primary key in each table is id. I don't have master table for each type